# Список папок и файлов в Assets

Tags: java, android, файлы, android-assets

Каким образом я могу получить названия папок в `assets`, а также список файлов в каждой из этих папок?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234529/list-of-files-in-assets-folder-and-its-subfolders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 2 способа:

1. Общепринятый: воспользоваться вызовом `AssetManager.list()`, где `AssetManager` можно получить из `Activity` через `getAssets()`
2. Нетрадиционный (почти недокументированный): `File file=new File("file:///android_asset/");` получим ссылку на корневой каталог `asset`, откуда уже можно раскручивать `File.listFiles()`

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к [соседнему ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738853/220996), что **список директорий** можно получить, например, рекурсивно:

```
public static List<File> getDirs(String dirPath) {
    List<File> resultDirsList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] dirFiles = new File(dirPath).listFiles();
    for (File file : dirFiles) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            resultDirsList.add(file);
            resultDirsList.addAll(getDirs(file.getPath()));
        }
    }
    return resultDirsList;
}
```

Аналогично можно получить **список файлов**:

```
public static List<File> getFiles(String dirPath) {
    List<File> resultFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] dirFiles = new File(dirPath).listFiles();
    for (File file : dirFiles) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            resultFilesList.addAll(getFiles(file.getPath()));
        } else {
            resultFilesList.add(file);
        }
    }
    return resultFilesList;
}
```